# Search for a text starting with a character and of specific length

Tags: php, regex

```
$sourceArray = array('venkat', 'bala', 'vignesh', 'vardan', 'harishv');
```

output must be an array which has values starting with 'v' and of length 6 chars.

Following must be the output array for the above sourceArray as input

```
$outputArray = ('venkat','vardan');
```

I tried `preg_grep('/^([v.]{6,6})/',$sourceArray));` which returned my an empty array.

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regular expression to use is:

```
/^v.{5}$/
```

Here is the code that produces what you've expect:

```
$sourceArray = array('venkat', 'bala', 'vignesh', 'vardan', 'harishv');

var_dump(
    preg_grep('/^v.{5}$/',$sourceArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your regex matches "a `v` or a dot `.` 6 times". You can use instead:

```
^v.{5}$
```

A `v`, followed by 5 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try `preg_grep('/^(v.{5})$/',$sourceArray);` (I've not checked this so may be wrong)

The '.' in the `[...]` structure is actually matching the period rather than any character

Answer (score 0):

You can have the regex doing it or you can do the following:

```
$results = array();
$startLetter = "v";

foreach($sourceArray as $key){
    if($key[0] == $startLetter && strlen($key) == 6 )
    {
        $results[] = $key;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps!